# How to save data offline with Orbeon Forms?

Tags: orbeon

We have tried to test Orbeon eForm to handle saving the data "Offline" after fill in the forms. We tried both version `PE 3.9.1` and `CE 3.9.0`, but it appears to not yet support an "offline" mode.

Comment: Are you using "Oberon" the programming language or "Orbeon" the XForms engine?

Comment: @marc_s Based on the tag, it appears the question is about Orbeon Forms. I updated the title to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

- Orbeon Forms doesn't support a **offline mode**, that would allow you to edit forms without an Internet connection. At this point, Orbeon Forms does not have an "offline mode", which would allow you to use it in your browser, without an Internet connection. Some work was done back in 2008, back then using [Google Gears](http://blog.orbeon.com/2008/08/what-we-have-been-up-to_17.html), but this isn't something that was further developed since then.

  One possible solution is to deploy Orbeon Forms plus your app on your users' computers. This is not always practical, as it requires that you provide Orbeon Forms plus your app as an installable package that users install on their machine, but it is something that some companies using Orbeon are doing.
- However, if you'd like users to just be able to **locally save the data they entered**, and you are creating forms with Form Builder, you can allow users to save the data they entered as a PDF, which they can for instance keep for reference.

Comment: Thank you Avernet for your reply,

Comment: We like to many features of Orbeon Forms in the way it can handle complicated Forms much, However, we will have a many pages complicated Form which will take a long time for a user to fill in.             (1) During these time, the communication via internet might be interrupt & disconnect. We just would like to have the way that user can continue to fill more data into the same form when he connect to retrieve this form later.   (2) Since it is a long and complicated form, the user need more time to fill-in and cannot finish within one time.

Comment: Could  you please help suggesting the way to solve this requirement ; if Orbeon Form is not longer support "Offline Mode" features

Comment: @PearaponJoe Since version 3.9, Orbeon Forms handles connection problems well. See: http://blog.orbeon.com/2011/03/be-persistent-if-it-fails-try-again.html So, if users fill out a form, an while doing so the connection goes down, they can continue, and can save the data when the connection comes back. But if they close the window before saving, they will loose their data. Also, dynamic aspects of the form (e.g. on-the-fly validation) will update again when the connection comes back.

Comment: Thank you very much "Avernet", We will try according to your suggestion :-D